# Custom Settings values not being queried

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have a custom settings which has the following columns:

Department || Sub Department || Employee || Serial Number

My code is :

```
for(CustomSettings__c cst: CustomSettings__c.getAll().values()) {
```

So the list should get fetched arranged in ascending order according to serial number.

Currently there are 10 records and I need to add 4 more . If I'm adding any extra , it's not coming up in my final output. Total records getting fetched is still 10 .
But if I change the serial number of a new record to say 5 , that is getting fetched and the old record , whose serial number is now beyond 10 , is not getting fetched.

In Developer console , all custom settings are getting fetched.

Please suggest.

Comment: What is your custom setting name? Is it Employee__c ? Also Employee__c is one of the 4 fields in the custom setting Employee__c? If so what's your requirement ? Do you want to apply a custom sort order on your custom setting based on the field 'Serial_Number__c'? What is the data type for the field 'Serial Number' ?

Comment: Typically you are saying that you are not able to retrieve more than 10 records even though if you have more than 10 .. am I right?

Comment: @Bennie Apologies , my custom setting name is something different . I have my custom settings defined . And I have some operations going on with records from other objects in a wrapper class . So for the Department || Sub Department || Employee combination in those records , I am fetching the Serial Number from custom settings of that combination and assigning it to a variable in wrapper class . And in the final display , records are displayed in order of serial number in Custom Settings.

Comment: @KiranMutturu Yes correct . That's the issue.

Comment: Are you adding the new records to the custom setting object using Apex?

Comment: @KiranMutturu No , adding manually.

Comment: Is your list hierarchical or list based..?

Also if LIst based, how many records are there in it without manipulaitng the records.

Also mention the way you are adding the records to existing custom setting

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the field type of Serial_Number__c field is it Number with length of 1 digit by any chance?

This looks like a strange issue. Also try once by directly using SOQL also. Like below,

```
List<Custom_Setting__c> customList = [select field1__c, field2__c from Custom_Setting__c];
```

If still not working, I think you might have to raise a ticket with salesforce support team.

Comment: It's already fetching 10 records , so will length be an issue still?

Comment: No the lenght should not be an issue, just use normal SOQL List<Custom_Setting__c> customList = [select field1__c, field2__c from Custom_Setting__c]; and it should be ok